# Extract non-Subsequences in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, sequence, subsequence

I have a data.frame:

```
1    2    3    4
A    B    C    D
A    B    C <NA>
A    C    D <NA>
A    C <NA> <NA>
A    D <NA> <NA>
A    E    G <NA>
A    G <NA> <NA>
A    K <NA> <NA>
A    D    J    P
```

Above data.frame means these sequences:

```
Sequence    Is this Non-subsequence?
A-B-C-D     (non-subsequence)
A-B-C       (subsequence of A-B-C-D)
A-C-D       (subsequence of A-B-C-D)
A-C         (subsequence of A-B-C-D)
A-D         (subsequence of A-B-C-D)
A-E-G       (non-subsequence)
A-G         (subsequence of A-E-G)
A-K         (non-subsequence)
A-D-J-P     (non-subsequence)
```

I want to extract only non-subsequences like this:

```
1    2    3    4
A    B    C    D
A    E    G
A    K
A    D    J    P
```

Is it possible to extract sequences which is not subsequence of any other sequence?

PS. Here is the code for making first data.frame.

```
data.frame(rbind(
        c('A','B','C','D'),
        c('A','B','C', NA),
        c('A','C','D', NA),
        c('A','C',NA,NA),
        c('A','D',NA,NA),
        c('A','E','G',NA),
        c('A','G',NA,NA),
        c('A','K',NA,NA),
        c('A','D','J','P')))
```

Comment: Do we have to check only the latest non sub sequence for the rows following?

Comment: `A-C` is sub-sequence of `A-C-D` too. isn't it?

Comment: @m0h3n Yes, it is.  Is it possible to extract sequences which is not subsequence of any other sequences?

Comment: how big is your dataset?